# getting artist calendar from songkick api - noob

Tags: javascript, api

This is probably a really easy thing to solve but I can't get it to work. I'm trying to get the artist calendar from the song kick api. Every time I run the code is says to use event.preventDefault() instead. And that i have  No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. I really don't know what any of that means. Can anyone help me?

Thanks

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#search").on("click", function () {
    $("div").html("");
    var artist = $("#name").val();
    if (artist) {
      $.get("http://api.songkick.com/api/3.0/events.json?artist_name=" + artist +"&apikey=myKey", function (data) {
    var concertResults = data.resultsPage.results.event;
    for (var i = concertResults.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (concertResults[i].uri) {
      $("#container").append("<div>" + concertResults[i].uri + "</div>");
     }
     }
      });
    } else {
      alert("You can't even get your favorite artist name right?")
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to use the Songkick API with Javascript you need to use something called JSON-P (http://json-p.org/)

It looks something like this:

```
$.getJSON("URL_TO_API&jsoncallback=?",
  function(data){
    // data is JSON response object
});
```

In your example, it would be:

```
$.get("http://api.songkick.com/api/3.0/events.json?artist_name=" + artist +"&apikey=myKey&jsoncallback=?",
  function(data){
     var concertResults = data.resultsPage.results.event;
     for (var i = concertResults.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
         ... // same as it is now
});
```

Hope this helps!